# finding the closest element with a particular id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 form-group">
    <input id="contact-info" class="form-control input-lg" name="contactInfo" placeholder="LINE ID" type="text" required autofocus />
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 form-group">
    <select class="form-control contact-type input-lg" name="contactType">
 <div>
```

Given an contact-type, how do I find the closest contact-info to that contact-type?

I tried doing the following but it failed:

```
$('.contact-type').closest('#contact-info')
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Why would you do that? ID's must be unique so `$('#contact-info')` should be enough unless you have multiple elements with the same id which is invalid.

Comment: The reason you are not get the jquery object maybe you have another .contanct-type . Can you show me all of your html markup or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your HTML markup, you can do:

```
$('.contact-type').closest('div').prev().find('#contact-info')
```

**[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

so `closest()` is not applicable in your case to get `#contact-info` because `#contact-info` is the child of a div which is the previous sibling of the parent div of your `.contact-type`

But since `id` is unique, you can just use:

```
$('#contact-info')
```

Comment: It's a class also `class="form-control contact-type input-lg`

Comment: Your description about closest is not right. "Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree." Here is jquery closest document: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: That's it, (your edit) … the ID is unique, `$('#contact-info')`